# Unable to start nodemanager of Hadoop YARN at OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, hadoop

After starting all other nodes, when I try to start nodemanager, it seems it has been opened and then automatically terminated. Like the following:

```
Yitongs-MacBook-Pro:hadoop timyitong$ sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
starting nodemanager, logging to /Users/timyitong/Dev/hadoop/logs/yarn-timyitong-nodemanager-Yitongs-MacBook-Pro.local.out
Yitongs-MacBook-Pro:hadoop timyitong$ jps
8981 DataNode
9300 Jps
9139 JobHistoryServer
8932 NameNode
9038 ResourceManager
```

I don't get any error, any exception, but the nodemanger is not there. And when I try to stop it, it says like this (the stopnodes.sh is just a script), which confirms that the nodemanager is not there:

```
Yitongs-MacBook-Pro:hadoop timyitong$ sh stopnodes.sh 
stopping namenode
stopping datanode
stopping resourcemanager
no nodemanager to stop
stopping historyserver
```

And I am not sure whether it is because nodemanager is not started, when I try to run the sample wordcount program, I always got my task pending forever.

My environment is OS X 10.8, Hadoop YARN 2.2.0.
And I already solved the java version issue with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acctually I used `bin/yarn nodemanger` to start the server directly and found out the problem. It is in my `yarn-site.xml` where I should not set the name of `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services` containing dots (.) like `mapreduce.shuffle`. After change `mapreduce.shuffle` to `mapreduce_shuffle`, the problem is solved.

Really don't understand why it does not allow dots, since I config everything according to this [blog post](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/), where this setting seems to be fine.

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mapreduce.shuffle should be mapreduce_shuffle . Please observe _ (underscore instead of dot). Also have a look at http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-nextgen-mapreduce.html